# Semantic-UI - How to clear dropdown cache

Tags: javascript, ajax, semantic-ui

How can I clear the cache of Semantic-UI dropdown that is set to fetch its content from remote URL? Here is my code so far. It doesn't send a new request to api.php whenever I click it i.e. it shows old data. However, when I search something, it sends the request.

```
$('#dd').dropdown({
        apiSettings: {
            url: '/api.php?q={query}',
            data: {query: ''},
            method: 'POST'
        }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `cache: false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `cache: false` to prevent caching of dropdown.

```
$('#dd').dropdown({
    apiSettings: {
        url: '/api.php?q={query}',
        data: {query: ''},
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false
    }
});
```

And here's on [clearing the cache in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828132/how-to-show-results-in-semantic-ui-api)

Comment: Ok it works, but you have to update the answer and put, cache:false inside apiSettings